# Geolocation only works after refresh

Tags: javascript, json, callback

Let me give you some info on the project. The goal of my project is to write an application that finds the closest trainstation to the user (using HTML5 geolocation).

The problem is: my function that prints the location on the screen doesn't wait for the geolocation to be in the sessionStorage. I know this has to be solved with a callback but I can't figure out how...

Here is the relevant code:

```
window.onload = function getLocation() {
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
    alert("Geolocation werkt niet bij jou, sorry.");
    }
}

function showPosition(position) 
{
sessionStorage.setItem("userLat", position.coords.latitude);
sessionStorage.setItem("userLong", position.coords.longitude);
}

function cb(data) 
{
var uLat = sessionStorage.getItem("userLat");
var uLong = sessionStorage.getItem("userLong");
var gegevens = data.Stations;
var result = Number.MAX_VALUE;
var nearIndex;
            for (var i = 0; i < gegevens.length; i++) 
            {
                var prev = haversine(uLat,gegevens[i].latitude,uLong,gegevens[i].longitude);
                if (prev < result)
                {
                    result = prev;
                    nearIndex = i;
                }
            }
            var x = document.getElementById("dbStation");
            x.innerHTML = "Je dichtsbijzijnde station is : " + gegevens[nearIndex].name;

}
```

The data is imported from an external JSON file by the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://data.irail.be/NMBS/Stations.json?callback=cb"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to call function that sets location to sessionStorage prior to callback, like:

```
function setSessionStorage() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("Geolocation werkt niet bij jou, sorry.");
        return false;
    }
}
//add the script
var oHead = document.getElementById('add');
var oScript = document.createElement('script');
oScript.type = 'text/javascript';
oScript.src = 'http://data.irail.be/NMBS/Stations.json?callback=cb';
oHead.appendChild(oScript);

oScript.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 'complete') {
        if( setSessionStorage() ) {
            cb();    //your callback
        }
    }
}
```